# Are there any industry-wide consequences as a result of Olympus' sale of their camera department?

Tags: olympus

Olympus has announced they're selling their camera department to JIT, who has said they will continue to build, sell and develop cameras.

What will be the effects - if any - to other camera companies or even people shooting on other systems?

Olympus isn't a particularly major player so I do not expect much, but I do wonder if it is a sign of the times to come.

Comment: This is getting awful close to *unreleased equipment* on the "... and it is **not** about..." list at [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). How this will play out is purely speculative.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is speculative about future events and products that may or not be offered. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and particularly [Should we allow questions about unreleased cameras?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/130/15871)

Comment: @MichaelC makes sense. My apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Olympus is part of the [micro-4/3 consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Four_Thirds_system) also including Panasonic and a number of other manufacturers of both bodies and lenses.  The departure of one major player with a long history and reasonable impact and experience may well reduce interest of quality lens manufacturers in catering to this format.  Olympus also shared flash foot standards (or non-standards, since there is far too much diversity) with Panasonic.  For cameras from a player with less of an established name, the interest in external flashes is likely to be less.

Again, this can affect the availability of third-party products for this format.

The sensor size is not used by a significant number of other systems, so sensor producers might be less interested in supporting this format in the long run as well.